# Performance issue on query over nested recursive objects

Tags: c#, performance, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I'm wondering what is the best way to select from a nested hierarchy of objects?
Assume that we a class `MyRecursiveObject` as below:

```
 public class MyRecursiveObject
 {
   public Int64 Id { get; set; }
   public MyRecursiveObject Parent { get; set; }
 }
```

How can I reach to maximum performance while selecting all parent Ids of an instance of  MyRecursiveObject?

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using linq-to-sql or linq-to-entities or just anything that is fastest?

Comment: If you're using linq on database derived data and SQL Server 2008+ it would be worth looking into hierarchyid: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677290.aspx.

Comment: I'm looking for both actually! Sometimes we are working on this issue in DAL and sometimes in logic layer.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server 2008+?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple loop instead of recursion:

```
public IEnumerable<long> GetAllParentIdsOf(MyRecursiveObject obj)
{
    MyRecursiveObject child = obj;

   while (child.Parent != null)
   {
       child = child.Parent;
       yield return child.Id;
   }
}
```

Sample:

```
MyRecursiveObject obj = new MyRecursiveObject {    
    Id = 1,
    Parent = new MyRecursiveObject {
        Id = 2,
        Parent = new MyRecursiveObject { Id = 3 }
    }
};

GetAllParentIdsOf(obj).ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);

// 2
// 3
```

Answer (score 1):

LinqToSql doesn't support walking trees of arbitrary depth.  You should write a sql function with a TSQL While loop to generate the results, and call that sql function from linqtosql.

Something like:

```
DECLARE @MyNodeID int
SET @MyNodeID = 42
  -- we're looking for the path from this ID back up to the root
  -- we don't know the length of the path.

DECLARE @MyTable TABLE
(
  int ID PRIMARY KEY,
  int ParentID,
)

DECLARE @ID int
DECLARE @ParentID int

SELECT @ID = ID, @ParentId = ParentId
FROM MyRecursiveObject
WHERE ID = @MyNodeID

WHILE @ID is not null
BEGIN

  INSERT INTO @MyTable (ID, ParentID) SELECT @ID, @ParentID

  SET @ID = null

  SELECT @ID = ID, @ParentId = ParentID
  FROM MyRecursiveObject
  WHERE ID = @ParentID

END

SELECT ID, ParentID FROM @MyTable  --results
```